# Running through two lists, and setting the value of matches to the proper index of a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I have a project I'm working on, and I can't figure out the best, or even a way to do this.

Originally, I had the things hard coded but I'm wanting to move to one that reads from a list, it reads from the list fine and adds them to the two vectors correctly, but getting those values into the proper place in the third vector is giving me some problems.

EDIT

I've got it adding the names back correctly now, but it's doing so without the color that should be added to special names.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
        for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++){
            if (playName == list[k]){
                playName = colorlist[k] + list[k];

                char* playName2 = new char[playName.length() + 1];
                strcpy(playName2, playName.c_str());

                PLAYER_NAMES.push_back(playName2);
                break;
            }
            else if (playName != list[k]){
                char* playName2 = new char[playName.length() + 1];
                strcpy(playName2, playName.c_str());

                PLAYER_NAMES.push_back(playName2);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd say this would be an excellent time to use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what was causing me problems.
this code was working perfectly fine,

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
    for (int k = 0; k < list.size(); k++){
        if (playName == list[k]){
            playName = colorlist[k] + list[k];

            char* playName2 = new char[playName.length() + 1];
            strcpy(playName2, playName.c_str());

            PLAYER_NAMES.push_back(playName2);
            break;
        }
        else if (playName != list[k]){
            char* playName2 = new char[playName.length() + 1];
            strcpy(playName2, playName.c_str());

            PLAYER_NAMES.push_back(playName2);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

but above it, was some code I didn't need to post so I didn't see the extra for loop until today. I was running a for 30 times, with another 30 runs for another, and then one with 4 for the list. Removing the extra loop caused everything to work just fine.